# passing url in another url

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this snippet:

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
                window.location = "details.php?trans=Automatic&&mileage=19,695&&eng=6&&ext=White Platinum Metallic&&stock=45411&&vin=2FMGK5D89DBD08967&&location=Palm Beach, FL&&price=$28,999&&photo=http://content.homenetiol.com/1535/67692/165x10000/2013-Ford-Flex-Limited/d0dbf839ecc3492a850bfc73a6d9099d.jpg";
                });
```

i want to pass the url of image `photo` in the url  but it didn't work

- why?
- how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode everything after ? via [`encodeURIComponent`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
            window.location = "details.php?"+ encodeURIComponent("trans=Automatic&&mileage=19,695&&eng=6&&ext=White Platinum Metallic&&stock=45411&&vin=2FMGK5D89DBD08967&&location=Palm Beach, FL&&price=$28,999&&photo=http://content.homenetiol.com/1535/67692/165x10000/2013-Ford-Flex-Limited/d0dbf839ecc3492a850bfc73a6d9099d.jpg");
  });
```